# dotenv with ES6 is returning on process.env undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I'm currently trying to connect to my database using process.env.MONGODB_URL, like that:

```
import dotenv  from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config()
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/eshop', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});
```

I tried console.log(process.env.MONGODB_URL) and is undefined.

The .env is in the root directory:

[image: project structure]

In the .env, i have something like that:

```
MONGODB_URL = "value"
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: I don't think the import is quite right? [How do I use dotenv with `import`?](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import) Try using `import 'dotenv/config'` instead?

Comment: The same thing happen, still undefined.

Comment: Try moving the `.env` file into the root? Since you're likely running the project from there

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem.